# What is the definition of phase lag and phase difference?

Tags: waves

What is the definition of phase lag and phase difference in waves and how are these two related?
Waves have always confused me,since it is very difficult to visualize them.
I have tried learning it from wikipedia but language is very difficult to understand as it contains difficult equations.
Please explain in simple words and with real life examples.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @John Rennie sir,i have  edited it

Comment: -1 for not explaining terms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you meet this the first time it can be a difficult concept to understand.

To get fit two friends decide to walk up and down a flight of stairs.
Let the steps be labelled $0$ to $10$.
So to go up and come down they have to ascend 10 steps and then descend 10 steps a total of 20 steps.  Call this one repetition or cycle of the exercise.

After a time it is noted that friend $A$ is on step 3 and going up and friend $B$ is on step 6 and going up.
So friend $B$ is 3 steps ahead of friend $A$ which is $\frac {3}{20}$ of a complete repetition (cycle).

Another way of describing this is to assume that a complete repetition (cycle) is equivalent to $360^\circ$ and so the fraction $\frac {3}{20}$ of a repetition (cycle) is equivalent to $\frac {3}{20}\times 360^\circ = 54^\circ$.

So we could say that friend $B$ **leads** friend $A$ by $54^\circ$ or we could say that friend $A$ **lags** behind friend $B$ by $54^\circ$.

So phase difference is a method of comparing the motions of two things which are oscillating cyclically.

Comment: thank you very much sir,it was great,but i generally encounter waves which have same frequency and wavelength,so the friends would be moving with same speed,so why is there a phase difference?please help sir,your example is excellent.

Comment: OK so just imagine the friends move at the same speed but one friend started 3 steps ahead of the other.

Comment: oh ok,so it is the initial difference that causes phase difference  for waves of same omega.

Comment: but sir,can you also please tell me what are coherent waves?