# What is the definition of the phase of a particles (points) on a travelling wave?

Tags: waves

If we have a travelling wave of equation $y=5\sin(\omega t-\pi x +0.5)\:\rm m$. I know that the phase is 0.5 but how can I visualize this and what is the definition of phase difference between 2 points along the same wave that are $n$ meters apart in the same medium?

Comment: You mean -*πx/m*  in your sin argument.  Draw two waves with their maxima 0.5m/π  apart, at a moment of your choice; they travel at the same speed.

Comment: @CosmasZachos What do the 2 waves you are talking about represent?

Comment: They represent [whatever](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54875/what-is-a-phase-of-a-wave-and-a-phase-difference?rq=1) you wish them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phase of an oscillation is the 'position' (usually expressed as an angle) that it has reached in its cycle. For example the phase of your wave at time $t$ and distance $x$ from some fixed point is $(\omega t -\pi[\text m^{-1}] x+0.5)$. It needs also to be stated whether the function is sine or cosine.

In your example, 0.5 is the *phase constant*.

The phase *difference*, $\Delta \phi$, at two points distance $\Delta x$ apart along the direction of propagation is the difference in these phase angles at any given time. Thus, $\Delta\phi=2\pi \frac {\Delta x}\lambda$. In your example, $\lambda = 2$m, so $\Delta \phi = 2\pi \frac {\Delta x}{2\text m}=\pi \ \text m^{-1} \Delta x$.